# Accessing an array with a variable in Jekyll/Liquid templating

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll, liquid

I have the following code in my template:

```
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    {% capture num_colors %}{{ site.colors | size }}{% endcapture %}
    {% capture color_index %}{{ forloop.index0 | mod: num_colors }}{% endcapture %}

    <a href="{{ post.url }}" class="post-box" rel="bookmark" title="{{ post.title }}">
      <div class="post-block {{ site.colors[color_index] }}">
        <div class="contents">
          <div class="cat-tag">
            {{ post.categories[0] | upcase }}
          </div>

          <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  {% endfor %}
```

This keeps returning nothing: `{{ site.colors[color_index] }}` even though `num_colors`, `color_index`, and `site.colors` will all return the correct things when I try and print them.

colors is defined  in my _config.yml as:

`colors: [light_blue, coral, yellow, teal, blue, deep_blue]`

I'm using a plugin to get modulus.  Basically I just want to attach a class for each post that will start over when its gone beyond the total number of colors. This seems straightforward so I'm confused.

Comment: I think it's because `capture` captures text in a variable. That might not work for array access. Can you  try `assign` for the index? But it's only a guess, I can't try it out myself in the moment for an answer.

Comment: @michaPau that did it! add the answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
{% capture num_colors %}{{ site.colors | size }}{% endcapture %}
{% capture color_index %}{{ forloop.index0 | mod: num_colors }}{% endcapture %}
```

by :

```
{% assign num_colors = site.colors | size %}
{% assign color_index = forloop.index0 | modulo: num_colors %}
```